# sock.bind() - TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python-3.x

My python code will not accept string, instead integer is required, why?

> sock.bind((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT)) Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "", line 5, in  TypeError: an integer is required (got
>   type str)

My code:

```
import socket
UDP_IP="localhost"
UDP_PORT="8080"
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))
```

Comment: Could you please provide the source code of your mentioned module with version.? The question seems unclear

Comment: UDP_PORT has to be an integer when used in `sock.bind`

Comment: Remove the quotes from UDP_PORT. Otherwise it is treated as string.